# This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

I am getting this error

> "This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false". "

when I deploy a website on IIS in Windows Server 2012. Can you guys tell me how to remediate this issue? 
thanks in advance

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" 
      type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, 
            System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">

      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.
            ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">

        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.
            ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, 
            Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
            requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />

        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.
            ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, 
            Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">

          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.
            ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, 
            Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
            requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />

          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.
            ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, 
            Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
            requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />

          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.
            ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, 
            Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
            requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />

          <section name="defaultDocument" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />

          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.
            ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
            requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />

        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>

  <runtime>
    <CompatSortNLSVersion enabled="4096" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>

        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <authentication mode="Windows">
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="10000">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
```

Comment: The error page usually also tells you on which line the error is observed. You should edit your question to make that explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Set the mode attribute of the `<authentication>` element in the `<system.web>` section.
please provide full error message snapshot and the web.config file code. and you can not set the windows authentication like this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="10000">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

For form authentication use code as below:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and for form authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="adAuthName" timeout="60" path="/"> </forms>
</authentication>
```